# How to get all purchases of an app for a given time duration using Rest?

Tags: android, android-pay, google-play-developer-api

I am trying to get all purchases (purchase tokens) for a given time duration using Rest API. i tried using "Google Play Developer API" but all i can find is "get" method for a particular purchase token, not any method to retrieve the list of purchases.

Answer (score 1):

So i received confirmation from Google Support saying there is no API for this.

> Unfortunately there is currently no way to call all aggregated
>   purchases/subscription data with the API. However, we do provide a way
>   to download our compiled CSV reports programmatically using gsutil:
>   https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?hl=en

But by default Google Play Console is exporting CSV reports on daily basis on Google Cloud Storage, so i am scheduling cronjob on these CSV reports.